# Divs next to scaled div jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I hover on a circle, the rest of them just jump while the circle animates. How do I fix that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#header').hide();
  $('#openSidebarIcon').hide();
  $('#seasonText').hide();
  $('#seasonDays').hide();
  $('#iconSidebar').hide();
  var firstLetter = '';

  $('.circle').hover(function() {

    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
      width: 300
    }, 200);
    var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'a';
    console.log(id);
    var fullDisplayText = '';

    switch (id) {

      case '#1a':
        fullDisplayText = 'REDMARKET';
        firstLetter = 'R';
        break;
      case '#2a':
        fullDisplayText = 'TINSER.NET';
        firstLetter = 'T';
        break;
      case '#3a':
        fullDisplayText = 'PHALLET';
        firstLetter = 'P';
        break;
      case '#4a':
        fullDisplayText = 'ANIMALZ';
        firstLetter = 'A';
        break;
      case '#5a':
        fullDisplayText = 'LEARNUNG';
        firstLetter = 'L';
        break;
      case '#6a':
        fullDisplayText = 'PROGRAMM';
        firstLetter = 'P';
        break;
      case '#7a':
        fullDisplayText = 'DOITURSELF';
        firstLetter = 'D';
        break;
      case '#8a':
        fullDisplayText = 'GAAMERZ';
        firstLetter = 'C';
        break;

    }

    $(id).text(fullDisplayText);

  }, function() {

    var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'a';
    $(id).text(firstLetter);
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
      width: 60
    }, 200);

  });

  $('#menulogo').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {

    $('#1').animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#2').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);

    }, 250);
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#3').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);

    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#4').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);

    }, 750);
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#5').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);

    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#6').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);

    }, 1250);
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#7').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);

    }, 1500);
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#8').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);

    }, 1750);

  }, 750);

});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<center>
  <img src='lib/img/tinserlogo.png' style='margin-top: 60px; opacity: 0;' id='menulogo'>
</center>
<center>
  <div id='1' class='circle' style='background-color: #FF0000;'><font id='1a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>R</font>
  </div>
  <div id='2' class='circle' style='background-color: #FF9100; margin-left: 20px;'><font id='2a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>T</font>
  </div>
  <div id='3' class='circle' style='background-color: #FFE600; margin-left: 20px;'><font id='3a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>P</font>
  </div>
  <div id='4' class='circle' style='background-color: #37FF00; margin-left: 20px;'><font id='4a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>A</font>
  </div>
  <div id='5' class='circle' style='background-color: #00FFF3; margin-left: 20px;'><font id='5a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>L</font>
  </div>
  <div id='6' class='circle' style='background-color: #001AFF; margin-left: 20px;'><font id='6a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>P</font>
  </div>
  <div id='7' class='circle' style='background-color: #FF00F3; margin-left: 20px;'><font id='7a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>D</font>
  </div>
  <div id='8' class='circle' style='background-color: #000000; margin-left: 20px;'><font id='8a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>C</font>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Well what exactly are you expecting to happen? I mean the circle needs some place to be animated. What should happen with the other circles?

Comment: Don't use the `<center>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to your `.circle` CSS rules to stop the jumping:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#header').hide();
  $('#openSidebarIcon').hide();
  $('#seasonText').hide();
  $('#seasonDays').hide();
  $('#iconSidebar').hide();
  var firstLetter = '';

  $('.circle').hover(function() {

    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
      width: 300
    }, 200);
    var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'a';
    console.log(id);
    var fullDisplayText = '';

    switch (id) {

      case '#1a':
        fullDisplayText = 'REDMARKET';
        firstLetter = 'R';
        break;
      case '#2a':
        fullDisplayText = 'TINSER.NET';
        firstLetter = 'T';
        break;
      case '#3a':
        fullDisplayText = 'PHALLET';
        firstLetter = 'P';
        break;
      case '#4a':
        fullDisplayText = 'ANIMALZ';
        firstLetter = 'A';
        break;
      case '#5a':
        fullDisplayText = 'LEARNUNG';
        firstLetter = 'L';
        break;
      case '#6a':
        fullDisplayText = 'PROGRAMM';
        firstLetter = 'P';
        break;
      case '#7a':
        fullDisplayText = 'DOITURSELF';
        firstLetter = 'D';
        break;
      case '#8a':
        fullDisplayText = 'GAAMERZ';
        firstLetter = 'C';
        break;

    }

    $(id).text(fullDisplayText);

  }, function() {

    var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'a';
    $(id).text(firstLetter);
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
      width: 60
    }, 200);

  });

  $('#menulogo').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {

    $('#1').animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#2').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);

    }, 250);
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#3').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);

    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#4').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);

    }, 750);
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#5').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);

    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#6').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);

    }, 1250);
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#7').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);

    }, 1500);
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('#8').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);

    }, 1750);

  }, 750);

});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<center>
  <img src='lib/img/tinserlogo.png' style='margin-top: 60px; opacity: 0;' id='menulogo'>
</center>
<center>
  <div id='1' class='circle' style='background-color: #FF0000;'><font id='1a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>R</font>
  </div>
  <div id='2' class='circle' style='background-color: #FF9100; margin-left: 20px;'><font id='2a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>T</font>
  </div>
  <div id='3' class='circle' style='background-color: #FFE600; margin-left: 20px;'><font id='3a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>P</font>
  </div>
  <div id='4' class='circle' style='background-color: #37FF00; margin-left: 20px;'><font id='4a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>A</font>
  </div>
  <div id='5' class='circle' style='background-color: #00FFF3; margin-left: 20px;'><font id='5a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>L</font>
  </div>
  <div id='6' class='circle' style='background-color: #001AFF; margin-left: 20px;'><font id='6a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>P</font>
  </div>
  <div id='7' class='circle' style='background-color: #FF00F3; margin-left: 20px;'><font id='7a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>D</font>
  </div>
  <div id='8' class='circle' style='background-color: #000000; margin-left: 20px;'><font id='8a' style='font-size: 48px; font-family: Futura; color: #FFFFFF;'>C</font>
  </div>
</center>
```